# What is the perforce bug review or bug triage feature?

Tags: perforce

I want to have the ability in Perforce where when one submits code, instead of getting submitted immediately, a different Perforce user gets notified so that they can review the changes to approve them before they actually get submitted.

Does any such feature exist in Perforce? Would it require a plugin? Does that feature exist in any code repo software? How would one really accomplish something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a whole category of code review tools, such as reviewboard, Reitveld, Gerrit, etc. Here's some links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Review_Board

Comment: Review Board is a good solution that has support for Perforce. To further extend the integration you could write a plugin/extension to the P4 Dashboard to show status within the P4V client. For further information on the Dashboard read this article on the Perforce Blog: http://www.perforce.com/blog/100621/pending-integrations-preview-dashboard

Answer (score 2):

I would do that using shelves.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/shelve.html

Comment: Using shelves is only a partial solution. Still +1.

Comment: Only a partial solution, but a really easy one to implement. We've used that at my company, and it's generally been "good enough" for us.